# How do I loop a youtube video at my website?

Tags: html, youtube-api

Im trying to use a Youtube video as a background of a website. I have tried setting the "loop" parameter as 1 as I have readed here (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop) but it doesnt work. This is the code i'm trying. All is working as intended but the loop parameter.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fcbm8SvlRYk?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&loop=1"></iframe>
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy paste from the link you've provided:

> Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in
>   IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player.
>   Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used
>   in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video,
>   set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value
>   to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID
```

Comment: Well as I see I should add the parameter playlist=fcbm8SvlRYk, but is not working anyway :S

Comment: It is working now, It seems like I had to close the window and open the html file again to succefully reload the page (weird, but it worked this way).

Comment: but the video will reload every time
how can i prevent it like in www.kolor.com where the video continue plying even if you turned off the internet after first auto replay?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code (added playlist parameter):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fcbm8SvlRYk?autoplay=1&controls=0&playlist=fcbm8SvlRYk&showinfo=0&autohide=1&loop=1"></iframe>
```

You should read the note in the loop parameter description located in the Google Developers link you provided:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop
**Note:** This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL:

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 
For me it's perfectly working

id="id1" src="src.abc.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"

Comment: The example provided is not a YouTube embed.